# How do I completely uninstall Android Studio from Windows 10?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

My Android Studio is not working properly. So I decided to uninstall it. It was impossible for me. The uninstaller provides a check box to uninstall the program that cannot be checked. How can I manually uninstall Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding it in c:program files or c:program files x86, then delete the entire Android Studio folder.

Also maybe try "repair" option first, if Android Studio offers it

Answer (score 0):

First go in Start -> TaskManager -> Check Android Studio -> End Task

Then Go in ControlPanel -> Uninstall Programs -> Select Android Studio
and it will delete all the files permanently from your device